# Map Pubsub topic Avro schema datatype to BigQuery

Tags: types, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub topic with the below avro schema attached. I would like to map it to BigQuery table schema using push-to-bq subscription type with use_topic_schema as true.

```
    {
    "name" : "columnA",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "bytes",
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 18,
      "scale" : 4
    }, "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "columnB",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "bytes",
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 19,
      "scale" : 4
    }, "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "columnC",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "bytes",
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 38,
      "scale" : 6
    }, "null" ]
  }
```

Tried to map it to below BigQuery schema,

```
{
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "columnA",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "columnB",
    "type": "NUMERIC"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "columnC",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }
```

But receiving the below incompatible error. This error is received for all 3 columns columnA, columnB, columnC.

```
│ Error: Error creating Subscription: googleapi: Error 400: Incompatible schema type for field NetSalesLocalCurrency: BYTES vs. FLOAT
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "pubsub.googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "actual_value": "FLOAT",
│       "expected_value": "BYTES",
│       "field_name": "ColumnC",
│       "reason": "INCOMPATIBLE_TYPE"
│     },
│     "reason": "INCOMPATIBLE_SCHEMA"
│   }
│ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery does not support converting the logical Avro type decimal into a numeric type in BigQuery. You need to use the BYTES column type   in your BigQuery table schema for the three columns. See the [BigQuery subscription schema compatibility documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#schema_compatibility) for what type conversions are supported.

Comment: so the loicalType decimal mentioned in avro schema does have any importance in determining the corresponding datatype of the BigQuery table. right?

Comment: The decimal type has no impact on the corresponding data type in the BigQuery table, no. Only some logical types are supported at this time, as detailed in the schema compatibility documentation.